# Mathematica 9 Linking with R

Tags: interoperability, rlink

I would like to run a batch job from within the current Mathematica .m file using "R CMD BATCH   &" (the job runs in the background when Mathematica proceeds with the current calculations. How can I do that in Mathematica 9?

Comment: I found a simple way to do this. Run["! R CMD BATCH <infile> <outfile> &"]; does this. We don't need RLink etc for this.

Comment: `Run` does not seem to be asynchronous to me, so I am not sure if this would work (correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: @Leonid - I am not an expert in mathematica. So, I don't know what you mean, but I tried the above one and it works for me. Mine was a mac machine. I am going to try on the Linux machine and if it does work there too, I'll make this as an answer. You are the one who developed the RLink thing right? Can you please tell me if there are any other ways to do this?

Comment: @preeti I meant that `Run` seems to wait until the result is ready (the batch), and block the computations of the main process. May be I am wrong, but that's what I saw on Windows. Re: RLink Yes, I wrote it, and I hope to post an answer based on it soon, just have to resolve one glitch.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin - ReadList[] seems to do that. It will wait until the job is done despite the '&' but Run seems to work fine (on mac)

Comment: @preeti Well, if `Run` works for you, all the better. I added an `RLink`- based solution, which may be a bit heavy-handed compared to `Run` (but `Run` did not work for me on Windows - in the sense that it was blocking).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin You can get functionality similar to `Run["!...&"]` on windows with this little call: `Import["!start \"\" /b /d \"" <> path <> "\" " <> program <> ".exe" <>
   args, "Text"]`, where you replace `path`, `program` and `args` with the relevant strings.

Comment: @MalteLenz Interesting. Thanks for pointing this out, will try.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a possible RLink - based solution. I will use Windows version, since it is easiest for me right now to test on Windows, but it should work on other platforms as well with a few obvious modifications.

First, here is a sample Mathematica script I used to test:

```
Needs["RLink`"]
InstallR[]

Pause[10]

REvaluate["{
     testdata <- rnorm(100)
     dim(testdata)<-c(10,10)     
     write.table(testdata,\"C:/Temp/testRdata.dat\")
}"]

Quit
```

which I stored in `C:\\Temp\\script.m`. The R code inside models your batch script code. The `Pause[10]` models some running time for the batch script. Now, here is what you do:

```
Needs["JLink`"];
InstallJava[];
LoadJavaClass["java.lang.Runtime"]
```

and then

```
Runtime`getRuntime[]@
   exec[{
      FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "math.exe"}], 
      "-script", 
      "\"C:\\Temp\\script.m\""}
   ]
```

This launches a separate process, which would execute the Mathematica script in `C:\\Temp\\script.m`, which, in turn, will load RLink and execute your R batch script.

This code returns immedaitely, so that your main kernel is not blocked, and you can compute with it regardless of whether or not the batch job has completed.

In fact, while I did not do it here, this can be further automated,so that you run your batch script from within Mathematica, first saving it to a temporary file. I may add this automation layer later.